# Can We use RecordStore database with Android?

Tags: java, android, rms

Can We use RecordStore database with Android ?

Comment: refer this [link](http://locify.googlecode.com/svn/branches/android/source/de/enough/polish/android/rms/SqlDao.java)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the `RecordStore` as defined by the package `javax.microedition.rms`, then no: Android is based on a modified version of Java SE. It doesn't provide the packages from Java ME.

However, Android (and Java SE) support much richer ways of storing data (for example [the `android.database` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html)).